# Documentum xCP - Failed to start webby at port 8888

Tags: maven, extjs, m2e, documentum, xcp2.x

I am using xCPDesigner 2.1 in order to build Documentum xCP 2.1 application. It seems that it uses Maven Eclipse m2e-webby plugin. 
I am unable to start Preview mode. Nothing happens within UI of the designer. In logs I can find

```
ERROR [TWorker-4] [internal.com.emc.xcp.builder.ui.util.PreviewStartJob:115] Failed to start webby at port 8888
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Exception occurred executing command line.
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.launching.AbstractVMRunner.exec(AbstractVMRunner.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.StandardVMRunner.run(StandardVMRunner.java:323)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.webby.internal.launch.WebbyLaunchDelegate.launchEmbedded(WebbyLaunchDelegate.java:310)
    at org.sonatype.m2e.webby.internal.launch.WebbyLaunchDelegate.launch(WebbyLaunchDelegate.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:855)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:704)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:697)
    at internal.com.emc.xcp.builder.ui.util.PreviewStartJob.startWebby(PreviewStartJob.java:107)
    at internal.com.emc.xcp.builder.ui.util.PreviewStartJob.run(PreviewStartJob.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\XCPDocumentum\xCPDesigner\jre\bin\javaw.exe" (in directory "C:\XCPDocumentum\xCPDesigner\Applications\test_two\test_two\target\m2e-webby"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.exec(DebugPlugin.java:838)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 12 more
```

There is some [discussion](https://community.emc.com/thread/191360) in support forum but with no updates for a month now. 
I don't have any experience with this plugin. 
Any clue with configuration options for this plugin and hints with this specific error message is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I migrated xCPDesigner to another environment and I didn't face this issue. Environment is pretty much the same, OS is Win 7. EMC /o\

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to a bug when handling non-English Windows operating systems.

Make sure that English is set as the language for your operating system in the regional settings. Afterwards, restart your operating system and try again.

This issue is reproducible when setting the language to Turkish as per my tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think, The problem with lengthy directory, so move forward your xCP designer, this might be the solution. simply D:/xCPdesigner , also try to give short names to any artifacts